# Using a header file, initialization file, and main file for structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I am having difficulty executing a program that I wrote with structs. My program has a header file, an initialization file, and a main file. When I compiled it, the compiler complained and later I found out that I forward declared my struct name as `Company` but initialized it using `company` so I changed it to `Company` but still the compiler complains after I did this. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code for my three files:

structs.h:

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

struct Company{
  double salary;
  int workers;
  int bosses;
}

#endif
```

initialization.cpp:

```
Company a = {1200340.99, 30000, 3};
Company b = {500320.85, 5000, 2};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "structs.h"

void PrintInfo(Company company){
  using namespace std;
  cout << "salary: " << Company.salary << endl;
  cout << "workers: " << Company.workers << endl;
  cout << "bosses: " << Company.bosses << endl;
}

int main(){
  PrintInfo(a);
  PrintInfo(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have missed the ';' at the struct :-)

Comment: Note that 'forward declared' means something different. There's no forward declaration in this code just regular declaration.

Comment: please make sure you show the *exact* error messages when writing your questions.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need a `;` after the definition of `struct Company`
2. In `PrintInfo` you need to reference the *object* `company` (lowercase c) and not the class `Company` (uppercase C), e.g.

   ```
   cout << "salary: " << company.salary << endl;   // lowercase c
   cout << "workers: " << company.workers << endl; // lowercase c
   cout << "bosses: " << company.bosses << endl;   // lowercase c
   ```
3. As `a` and `b` is initialized (globally) in a different source file you must redeclare them with external linkage in the source file that need to access them using the `extern` keyword, e.g.

   ```
   // main.cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include "structs.h"

   extern Company a;
   extern Company b;

   /* ... */
   ```

   Consider initializing `a` and `b` where they are used instead:

   ```
   int main() {
       Company a = {1200340.99, 30000, 3}; // Init here.
       Company b = {500320.85, 5000, 2};   // Init here.

       PrintInfo(a);
       PrintInfo(b);
       // return 0; // Unnecessary in main function.
   }
   ```
4. In function `PrintInfo`, as you are not modifying the argument you should pass the class `Company` as reference to const to avoid copying, i.e. declare the function using this:

   ```
   void PrintInfo(const Company& company)
   ```

Comment: Also some `extern` is missing for `a` and `b` in the OP's sample.

Answer (score 2):

A structure requires a ';' at the end

```
struct Company{
  double salary;
  int workers;
  int bosses;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, the code in `main.cpp` knows nothing about `a` and `b` in your `initialization.cpp`.

You need to either add an `extern` declaration in `structs.h` or move those into `main.cpp`.

But, you should also consider not making them global variables, like this:

```
int main()
{
    Company a = {1200340.99, 30000, 3};
    Company b = {500320.85, 5000, 2};
    PrintInfo(a);
    PrintInfo(b);
    return 0;
}
```